# What does HasDefaultValueSQL do in a database first implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

We are using Entity Framework 3.1, and have some references to .HasDefaultValueSQL.

```
entity.Property(e => e.UpdateTimeStamp)
    .HasColumnType("datetime")
    .HasDefaultValueSql("GetDate()");
```

We have to change GetDate() for reasons, and this is only in one spot in our code but no local knowledge in entity framework.

My question is, what does the value in HasDefaultValueSQL do in a database first implementation?

We have changed and tested the value to multiple other strings and so far we feel that it's not used, but can not find any sort of documentation or guide showing what it does, and what changing it would do in our case.

Comment: None, it is used for code-first where the entity definitions will define the schema.  Make sure migrations/schema initialization are turned off if EF is meant to be operating in DB-First otherwise you could end up with validation exceptions when running the application after making manual schema changes.

Comment: @StevePy that was our current working theory, we just have no proof of it, which makes presenting that to the powers that be a less than ideal option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you pass to `HasDefaultValueSql` is not used by EF in a database first scenario, however the fact you call that method at all when configuring the property on the model does have an effect.

When you do an insert it’ll mean that if the property has the CLR default value (null, or 0 for int, empty GUID, etc.) it will omit that column from the insert statement; it will refrain from explicitly setting the column to that null (etc.) value as it is of the understanding that the database has a default value of some kind (presumably the one supplied but it doesn’t check this, just assumes something is configured on the DB).

So, if you have a default in the database, you should set that in your model to make use of it.

Another good reason I’ve discovered to model the default SQL accurately is that even if using database first, your unit tests might use a code first approach (ie use your model to build a DB to test against). And so having that unit test DB be accurate is a good idea.